# iPhone drop test time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I am working on this problem. Here is the background information:

You are working at a company in a skyscraper with n floors, and the management wants to know how well iPhones do if they are thrown out of very high windows. The idea is that the iPhones aren’t affected at all by this below some specific floor F . When dropped from any floor below F , they do not break; when thrown from floor F and above, they break.

I need to develop a strategy to determine floor F that takes O(kn^(1/k)) trials where I have k >= 3 iPhones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the ith phone (1<=i<=k) at increasing multiples of n^(1-i/k) (rounded).
When the phone breaks, we need to use the rest of the phones to search a range of n^(1-i/k).

Hence, for phone i, it searches in a range of n^(1-(i-1)/k) at increasing multiples of n^(1-i/k). Hence we drop the phone at most O(n^(1/k)) times for each phone.

Since there are k phones, that means it takes O(kn^(1/k)) trials.